# How to allow Terminal to Find Commands without Export PATH?

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line

The terminal on my Macbook Pro cannot find any commands until I enter this before every session I use :

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

How can I make it so that I do not have to enter this every time I use the terminal to use commands?

Comment: Please add the content of /etc/paths (`/bin/cat /etc/paths`) and ~/.profile|.bash_profile|.bashrc (Example: `/bin/cat ~/.bashrc`). The latter three user profiles may not exist

Comment: Also please post which shell you're using: echo $SHELL.

Answer (score 1):

Each shell has ‘profile’ files, the contents of which are run when the shell is launched. For bash, this includes `~/.bash_profile`. Create this file and add any commands you wish to run in that file, then relaunch your shell.

Comment: Command not found and permission denied. So I tried entering the export PATH and using sudo to do this but still it says command not found.

Comment: @sawreals What are the exact commands you are using and what are the exact errors?

Comment: The paths in the sawreals' PATH variable (which has to be set to get any command working except the shell) are standard paths already set globally (theoretically)! Something different has to be wrong!

Comment: First I enter `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` to be able to enter anything into the terminal then `sudo ~/.bash_profile` gives command not found.

Comment: @sawreals You need to create the file. That’s a file path, not a command, so you can’t execute it (the sudo is redundant). `touch ~/.bash_profile` to create it and/or use your editor of choice.

Comment: @klanomath A very good point, something is completely broken here, what steps were taken by OP before this questions was posted?

Comment: Perhaps a factory reset of my Macbook could correct this problem?

Comment: Ok so I fixed the problem. I entered `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` as I did before and then entered `chsh -s /bin/zsh` and restarted the terminal application and am now able to enter commands as normal. For more information on `zsh` in MacOS Catalina please look here: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT208050

Comment: @sawreals No, this won't be necessary...(sledgehammer to crack very tiny nuts)

Comment: @sawreals That’s worked because zsh does not use bash’s profile files like ~/.bash_profile. Check the contents of that file.

Comment: I took a look in Vim and it looks like I may have 2 versions of python installed  (3.5 and 3.6) @grg